# Session variable gets updated when modifying locally

Tags: asp.net, session, c#-4.0

Why my session variable gets updated when i am only modifying it in a local variable. If they share the same references then i wonder why its only updating in this scenario not in any other case where i use the similar code.

```
 private void AddRefCodeToDTandConvertUnitValue(string StrRefCode)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = Session["dataTable"] as DataTable;
            if (!dt.Columns.Contains("refCode"))
                dt.Columns.Add("refCode", typeof(String));
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows[i]["refCode"] = StrRefCode;
                if (DrpUnits.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[i]["Units"].ToString()) != null)
                dt.Rows[i]["Units"] = DrpUnits.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[i]["Units"].ToString()).Value;                                
            }
        }
```

Comment: `Session Variable Gets Updated` what is the issue? how you are getting the updated result from `Session`?

Comment: Can you more clear your question with code? Which place you will put this code?

Comment: i fetched the values of session variable in the local datatable. Then modified the datatable. But din't update the session variable. But the changes made in local datatable are reflecting in the session variable without updating the session variable. I think instead of copying values it is copying reference of session variable in datatable. My question is why? why it is copying reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced same issue in one of my web application.

It is because when you are typecasting Session value into your DataTable it will point to the same memory location.

To avoid updation of Session variable you can deep clone it while typecasting. It will create another DataTable instance at another memory location with same value.